# Visual Basic App Connect to SQL Server as Computer User

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, connection-string

I have made a Simple CRUD application made in VB with the data stored in SQL Server on my local machine.

Within the Database security I have made Database Roles and assigned permissions accordingly, and added my (Domain) Computer user account into the Role.

My connection string is;

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Assets;Integrated Security=SSPI
```

Now when I run my application it assumes the dbo role instead of the user who is running the application. As this is intended to run on a central machine and have multiple users connecting to it, with different permissions, what changes do I need to make so that I connect using my domain user account?

When I run commands in SSMS with the EXECUTE AS USER command the permissions apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to connect via their Windows login, your connection string is fine. However, you need to recongifure your security model. Ideally, you'll want to create one Active Directory group per application role. Then, you'd add users' Windows accounts to the appropriate AD group. Now, on SQL Server, you'd add the AD groups to the appropriate database roles.

For example, you create a database role "db_read_only". You'd create an AD group "MyApp.ReadOnly", using your company's AD group naming convention of course. You'd then add MyApp.ReadOnly to your database's db_read_only DB role. Then, John Doe wants read-only access to your app, so he'd request to be added to AD group MyApp.ReadOnly.

Your app roles define how many AD groups and DB roles you'd need. You might have MyApp.Admin, MyApp.DataEntry, MyApp.Approver... whatever.